# cannot set background = UIColor.clearColor() for UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift

I can set `clearColor` for `UIButton`

```
var btn = UIButton()
btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

But I can't set this for `UIBarButtonItem`.

Comment: According to my Knowledge we  cant set background colour  for BarButton

Comment: Either you customise the button and add it to BarButton

Comment: Either use a `UIControl` or set background image.

Answer (score 0):

You could either create a button and then use the `UIBarButtonItem(customView: yourButton)` init, or you could set the bar button item tintColor globally:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

I presume you don't want to have a clear color for all your bar button items, so the first solution is probably the way to go here.

Answer (score -1):

```
  var customFilter: UIButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
 customFilter.setImage(UIImage(named: "filter.png")!, forState:   .Normal)
 customFilter.setTitle("Filter", forState: .Normal)
 customFilter.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0), forState: .Normal)
 customFilter.sizeToFit()
 customFilter.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.filterTapped), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
   customFilter.layer.cornerRadius = 5
customFilter.backgroundColor = UIColor.yourcolor()

var btn: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customFilter)
```